# why name of string contain address of itself in c

Tags: c, string, memory-address

How is it possible, name of string contains address of string - YES ok
but its (name of string) address should be different, but it is the same

NOT only that , `*str` gives the first character - that's ok
but `*str` is nothing but value at(**6356737**), in this code
but that itself is equal to **6356737** and not 'f'(which is nothing but str[o])

```
int main()
{
    char str[] = "fdsgugreui";
    printf("\nstr=%u,&str=%u : *str = %c\n",str,&str,*str);
    int i=0;
    while(str[i] != '\0'){
        printf("\n&str[%d] =%u : str[%d] = %c\n ",i, &str[i], i, str[i]);
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

//result...

```
str=6356737,&str=6356737 : *str = f
&str[0] =6356737 : str[0] = f
&str[1] =6356738 : str[1] = d
&str[2] =6356739 : str[2] = s
&str[3] =6356740 : str[3] = g
&str[4] =6356741 : str[4] = u
&str[5] =6356742 : str[5] = g
&str[6] =6356743 : str[6] = r
&str[7] =6356744 : str[7] = e
&str[8] =6356745 : str[8] = u
&str[9] =6356746 : str[9] = i

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.150 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I cannot understand why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` is the char array which decays into a pointer to the first element of the `char` array - which is same as `&str[0]`.

Note that value-wise `str` and `&str` are the same but their type is different. `str` decays into pointer - so it becomes `char*` but the second one is `char(*)[11]` (note when you pass array name as operand of `&` it won't decay into pointer) which is a pointer to an array object.

The correct way to print address is `printf("%p",(void*)str);` and this also will be same for other pointer variables.

`str[0]` is the content of the array `str` at the position `0`. That's it - it has nothing to do with having an address, It is a `char`. In your case `str[0]` is nothing but `'f'`.

What is array decaying?

So in most situations, the array is converted to the pointer to the first element. This is array decaying. Notice the case here `str` is an array of `char`s - when we use `str` in `printf` it is converted to a pointer to the first element of itself which is address of `str[0]` and the pointer contains that value. This explains why you get the value of `&str[0]` when you printed `str`.

There are a few exceptions to array decaying:

1. it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator.
2. the `_Alignof` operator, or
3. the unary `&` operator, or
4. is a string literal used to initialize an array.

The fun part is `&str` here you see it is an operand to `&` address of operator - this is an exception where the decaying won't happen. So `&str` is a pointer to an array object. The type is `char (*)[]`. And yes, as you sae it will be of the same value as that of `str` or `&str[0]` but it's type is completely different.

What is `char(*)[SIZE]`?

It is denoting a pointer to an array of chars which has the size of `SIZE`. There are `SIZE` elements in the array.

Is `char (*p)[SIZE]` same as `char* p[SIZE]`?

**Noo.** It is not. First one is a pointer to an array of `char`s which has `SIZE` number of elements.

`char* p[]` is an array of `char*`-s. These are not the same. The first one is denoting a single pointer and the second is an array of pointers.

Another thing is - for pointers there are two things that matter

- The value of the pointer.
- The type of the pointer.

The second one dictates how the pointer arithmetic will be depending on the size of the type of object it points to. In here also you saw that `&str` and `str` has same value but not the same type. You will be surprised if you see these statement and print it.

```
printf(" &str+1 = %p str+1 = %p\n",(void*)(&str+1),(void*)(str+1));
```

> *Hint*: The first one `&str` is a pointer to an array. The second is pointer to a `char`.

Comment: I didn't understand "decays into pointer " ? what do you mean by this

Comment: @STG284.: Look for the edits - I will explain it to the basics

Comment: Can you please tell me about this - char(*)[],  is this char * [] and char * are same

Comment: @STG284.: Check the answer

Comment: is it necessary to typecast to void* in printf("%p",**(void*)str**);

Comment: @STG284.: Yep it is.:)

Comment: but i tried it prints the same address, with and without (void *) : so what is its use

Comment: @STG284.: I will tell you --give me some time...is it ok?

Comment: @STG284.: Because the C standard says so.  *The argument to `%p` shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.* Even if it works for your case..it is not the right way to do this.

Comment: Where do I find this C STANDARD site or pdf something ,